# Angular router - what is the difference between route containg variable and nested children route?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to display list of users when navigating to `/users` and display an edit form for a specific user, when navigating to `/users/123`.

I have an Angular Router configured as below and it works fine

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersListComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'users/:id',
    component: EditUserComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

But when I try to use `children` route it doesn't work and `/users/123` displays `UsersListComponent`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: EditUserComponent,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];
```

What is the difference between these two approaches, why the 2nd one doesnt work and which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second example to work you'll need a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside the template of `UsersListComponent`:

The first example works because both paths are on the same level and not in a parent/child relation.

> which one is correct?

Usually in these kinds of scenarios you want to have them on the same level, because they're entirely different components, but if you wanted `EditUserComponent` to be displayed inside of `UsersListComponent` then you'd go for the second approach.

Answer (score 1):

It will work. You need a router-outlet tag in your User List component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'user-list',
  template: `<h1>List</h1>
    <div><a [routerLink]="['/users/999']">Click This User To Navigate</a></div>
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>`,
})
export class UserListComponent  {
  
}

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-user',
  template: '<h1>edit user</h1><p>{{id}}</p>',
})
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit  {
  id: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
  }
}
```